# Database design for reverse-auction platform

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-design

The idea is for a reverse auction platform where users post their auction for certain services and providers bid on it with their offers.

Should I be splitting my tables? For example the auction can be for a new service or to replace an existing service so there are questions that are specific to each selection.

Should I move those columns into a separate table for that option?

Here is a diagram of what I've come up with so far:
[Database Diagram image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kdIaV.png)

Am I on the right track here?

What data type should I use for columns where there will be an list of options to choose from in the auction form? For example, ***cash_back*** will give the user a range of choices as:

1. Donate to Charity
2. Deposit to my account
3. Credit Voucher

Is the norm to use a string for this column with the respective strings or do I create a new table for the options and use the option_id as a foreign key in this table?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read the Stack Overflow [help file](http://stackoverflow.com/help), which will help you ask good, on topic questions. As posed, your question is a request for design assistance, which is outside the scope of this site. Try to narrow your focus to a specific programming issue, and you're more likely to receive useful guidance.

Comment: Agree with above... also - I'm pretty sure you're unfamiliar with the standard practices for Ruby on Rails table design... I strongly recommend you read through the Rails guides. Preferably all of them - it will really give you a leg up on how to use Rails the way Rails expects (which will make your life so much easier). The relevant one for tables is: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html I say this because your design diagram is full of natural keys... and that is not standard practice in Rails and will be difficult to maintain by comparison.

Comment: Thank you. I don't have anyone in my circle that knows programming so I thought this would be the best place to ask for help. I'll definitely try the Rails Guides and will be more specific next time with my questions!

Answer (score 0):

I think it is worth discussing here Rails philosophy and database design generally.

As I often say you can have a database for your application, or you can have an application for your database.  In the latter, database design is important.  In the former, it usually follows application design.

What this means is that you probably, assuming this is a Rails app, don't want to design your database at all.  What you want to do is design your application object model and let Rails design your database.  You won't get a great db design that way, but it will be good enough.

The tradeoff is that when you go this way, you often end up with the database as effectively owned by the application and it may not be safe to have other apps add or modify the data in the database.  Moreover it may be harder to come up with really good reports, but where you put in most of your time will be better optimized (your main app).

TL;DR:  If you want a database for your app and using Rails or Django, then stop thinking about database design, but realize that while this optimizes some pathways today, it makes many other things harder down the road.

Comment: Thanks Chris! That makes a lot of sense and will help if I can let Rails do the database work without having to think too much about it. The only thing I am still confused about is if I should be splitting some of my models/tables into separate tables as per my first example (maybe it will be answered in the Rails Guides that Taryn recommended which I haven't gone through yet)